# facebook login returning 0 codeigniter instead of trying many solutions

Tags: codeigniter

I trying to get facebook login functionality to work. My problem is that the userid is returning 0. Below is my code.

```
include_once APPPATH."libraries/facebook-api-php-codexworld/facebook.php";
    $appId = 'xxxxx';
    $appSecret = 'xxxxx';

    $redirectUrll = base_url() . 'register/';
    $fbPermissions = 'email';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $appId,
        'secret' => $appSecret

    ));

    $_REQUEST += $_GET; 
    $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
    print_r($fbuser);
    if ($fbuser) {
            $userProfile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');
            // Preparing data for database insertion
            $userData1['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
            $userData1['oauth_uid'] = $userProfile['id'];
            $userData1['fname'] = $userProfile['first_name'];
            $userData1['lname'] = $userProfile['last_name'];
            $userData1['email'] = $userProfile['email'];
            $userData1['status'] = 'Active';
            //$userData['gender'] = $userProfile['gender'];
            //$userData['locale'] = $userProfile['locale'];
            // $userData['profile_url'] = 'https://www.facebook.com/'.$userProfile['id'];
            //$userData['picture_url'] = $userProfile['picture']['data']['url'];
            // Insert or update user data
            $userID = $this->home->checkUser($userData1);
            if(!empty($userID)){
            $data['userData1'] = $userData1;
            $this->session->set_userdata('userData1',$userData1);
        } else {
            $data['userData1'] = array();
        }
    } else {
        $fbuser = '';
        $data['authUrl'] = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$redirectUrll,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));
    }
```

Comment: what on here `print_r($fbuser);` ??

Comment: check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi

Comment: Rephrasing questions to remove pleas for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this code:

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
              'appId'  => $appid,
              'secret' => $secret,
              'cookie' => true
     ));       

    $userId = $this->facebook->getUser();

    if($userId == 0){

        $access['scope'] = 'email,publish_actions,user_birthday,user_location,user_about_me,user_hometown';
        $access['redirect_uri'] = base_url() . 'register/';

        $url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($access);
        redirect($url);

  } 
  else
  {
       $access = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
       $user = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email,birthday,gender,locale,picture',array('access_token'=>$access));
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($user);exit;

        $userData1['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
        $userData1['oauth_uid'] = $user['id'];
        $userData1['fname'] = $user['first_name'];
        $userData1['lname'] = $user['last_name'];
        $userData1['email'] = $user['email'];
        $userData1['status'] = 'Active';

        $userID = $this->home->checkUser($userData1);
        if(!empty($userID))
        {
          $data['userData1'] = $userData1;
          $this->session->set_userdata('userData1',$userData1);
        } 
        else {
            $data['userData1'] = array();
        }

      redirect('/login');//Redirect To Success Page

  }
```

I hope it will work for you!!

Comment: It works but i m getting 0 userid and it is going in if condition i want to save data to the database so how can i achieve it ?

Comment: You must ensure that your access token is active. Or maybe you're in logout condition. Or try to clean the cookies and cache from your browser (ctrl+shift+del).Then you need to print $userId and exit code.And check what you get?

Comment: i am using the same code don't know why it is returning 0 i had clear cookie and access token is active means ?

Comment: You can get access token from "$this->facebook->getAccessToken();".

Comment: when i write $userId = $this->facebook->getUser();
its giving me error    and when i write $userId = $facebook->getUser();   its working but user id 0 :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139950/discussion-between-sona-and-jay-kareliya).